# Hyphen too wide in texttt when combined with microtype

Tags: hyphenation, microtype, typewriter

I'm currently writing a paper with a lot of code references. I want to typeset class and method names using `\texttt{}`. I am explicitly indicating word splitting points using e.g. `\texttt{Very\-Long\-Word}`

I would also like to use the `microtype` package. However, the width of the hyphen character is different in texttt and normal text.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord \texttt{Very\-Long\-Word} VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord 
\end{document}
```

If the microtype package is commented out, the width is uniform.

To emphasize the size difference one can add a vertical line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning,arrows}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\methodName}{\code{Very\-Long\-Word}}
\begin{document}
VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord \texttt{Very\-Long\-Word} VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord VeryLongWord 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=0.1pt]($(current page.north)+(\textwidth/2,-2cm)$)--($(current page.north)+(\textwidth/2,-8cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is probably due to the fact that the microtype package implements character protrusion.

Is there anything I can do to use the `microtype` package and still have uniform hyphens?

Comment: I see no difference in the width of the hyphen without and with microtype, only the protrusion changes.

Comment: Are you preparing for printing the 42-line Bible?

Comment: the `-` in monospace is longer than the `-` in roman as it's a monospace font, so `-` is as wide as `M` using `microtype` has no effect on this width, it just causes both of the `-` to protude in to the margin.